# Git: Clean up commits after moving subdirectory into a new repo

Tags: git

I originally had one large repo that I've since broken up into a couple more manageable repos by doing the following:

```
git checkout my_branch
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter my_subdir my_branch
git merge --strategy=ours master    # keep the content of this branch, but record a merge
git checkout master
git merge my_branch             # fast-forward master up to the merge
```

This successfully kept all of the commit history, but since the large repo was huge the commit history for my new repos is huge even though some of them only contain a handful of files.  One repo has 814 commits, but only the last 5 apply to files still in the repo.

Is there anyway to tell git that I don't need the other 809 commits anymore?

Comment: `git filter-branch` does not delete commits; instead, it copies the filtered commits to *new* commits, then sets the filtered name—in this case, `my_branch`—to point to the newest copied commit. So if you had about 800 commits to start with, and this wound up copying 5 commits that had files in the subdirectory, you now have 800+5 commits. You then merged your new commits with your old commits, fusing them together to make the collection really solid—obviously not what you intended!

Comment: Presumably, what you want is to *not* do that last merge, but rather to *replace* your old name `master` with the latest copied commit. Then you can delete any other branch and tag names that retain the original commits, so that you don't see them, and `git gc` will eventually remove them.

Comment: Yeah, my repo was a total mess and I tried to save as much of the history as I could as I untangled it. In this one case, I really didn't need to do that and now I'm just trying to figure out the best way forward at this point. Since I've already done that last merge (and commited new stuff) is there any recourse?

Comment: You could redo the filter-branch, skipping the merge. In general the whole "rewrite a bunch of history" thing (copy commits to new chains and make everyone using the old ones switch over) is a big pain that doesn't pay off much, so you should be *really* sure it's *really* important, before bothering.